# Selenium server could not connect

Tags: selenium-ide

Selenium server could not connect

[image]

Description : Run the script and In Log table display the error.

Error : Selenium server could not connect, have you started the selenium server.

Comment: can you close your IDE and reopen and see this works?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this link. Your settings might be trying to use webdriver to connect to a selenium server. You likely do not want this feature on, or you need to specify a valid selenium server. Follow the instructions to open the options dialog:

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10024/error-could-not-connect-to-selenium-server-have-you-started-the-selenium-server

> You're probably in "webdriver playback" mode. There are two ways to
>   play back tests that were recorded with Selenium IDE: using Selenium
>   IDE, or using Webdriver. If you're using Webdriver, you have a client
>   that connects to a server (sometimes a remote server), so you have to
>   start the server component in order to let the client (Selenium IDE)
>   connect.
>
> To turn off Webdriver playback, go to the Options dialog, and uncheck
>   "Enable Webdriver playback". Then restart the browser you're running
>   Selenium IDE in.